# Recover text file deleted from trash on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, terminal, data-recovery

how can I use the `grep` command in termainal to undelete my text file?

Comment: You can't use grep to undelete files.

Comment: If it's still opened by a process, you can [recover it with gdb/lldb](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/448065) [(via)](https://superuser.com/q/439196)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, stop working with the disk containing your textfile. Boot from another system.

Then, You can try:

- [PhotoRec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec)
- [Data Rescue](http://www.tri-edre.fr/english/datarescue.html)
- [Disk Warrior](http://www.alsoft.com/diskwarrior/index.html)

Comment: PhotoRec looks great! (if you don't mind a ncurses-like interface)